# Ruby on Rails - Delayed Job - Return job id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I got a Rails app which basically crawls a lot of RSS feeds. Each feed has a crawl interval like for example 3 hours.

The problem is, since it's crawling more and more feeds every day(more and more get added) sometimes the 3 hours are over before the feed actually got crawled by delayed job. That results in more and more jobs. I hope my problem is clear.

So what I want to do is basically save the current job id for each feed and check if the job has already finished before adding the new job for that feed to the queue.

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

add a boolean variable for example "in_progress" to your delayed job table. always when a job starts, set this attribute to true. if the job is finished, update it to false. Only start jobs, if the "in_progress" attribute is false, otherwise skip this feed.